# building a table

Tags: javascript

[image]Why is this coming back undefined if i am using the decoded list name

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGetBoilerEFs").click(function () {

            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pjBoilerEmissionsCalculations')/items?";
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });


            function onSuccess(data) {
                var items = data.d.results;

                var button1 = "click me!"
                var fullResults = '<table id="tableCars" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><b>Title</b></td>' + '<td><b>source Type</b></td>' + '<td><b>factorID</b></td>' + '<td><b>pollutantName</b></td>' + '<td><b>pollutantEFValue</b></td>' + '<td><b>pollutantEFUnits</b></td>' + '<td><b>boilerUnitID</b></td>' + '<td><b>EDIT BUTTON</b></td>' + '<td><b>DELETE BUTTON</b></td>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                    var editprojinput = "<input type='button' class='contentbutton' value='Edit' onclick='EditProject(" + items[i].factorID + "," + i + ")' class='editprojbutt'/>";
                    var deleteprojinput = "<input type='button' class='removebutton' value='Delete' onclick='DeleteProject(" + items[i].factorID + "," + i + ")' class='delprojbutt'/>";

                    fullResults += '<tr>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].Title + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].w01u + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i]._x006f_to5 + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i]._x0070_we5 + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i]._x0074_oi + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i]._x0071_d01 + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + items[i].boilerUnitID + '</td>';

                    fullResults += '<td>' + editprojinput + '</td>';
                    fullResults += '<td>' + deleteprojinput + '</td>';


                    fullResults += '</tr>';
                }
                $('#resultsTable').append(fullResults);
            }
            function onError(error) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>

    function EditProject(ItemID, rowID) {
        alert("hello ! " + ItemID + " and " + rowID + " I am an alert box ");
    }

</script>
<input type="button" id="btnGetBoilerEFs" value="Make Boiler EF Table" />
<br /><br />
<table id='tableCars' style="width: 100%;" border="1 px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="resultsTable" style="width: 100%"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your for syntax is not correct:  `for (var i = 0; i "; var deleteprojinput = "";`

While not undefined, your fullResults string concatenation is strange as there are no delimiters between all of the string values. It generates this:

`'Titlesource TypefactorIDpollutantNamepollutantEFValuepollutantEFUnitsboilerUnitIDEDIT BUTTONDELETE BUTTON'`

Lists have display names and internal names. Which is "pjBoilerEmissionsCalculations"?

Comment: Thats display name i believe of the list itself

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have some of the internal names of the fields wrong.

Clearly `Title`, which you have as `items[i].Title` and `sourceType`, which you have as `items[i].w01u` *are* returning the correct values.  Which makes me think that if all the rest are `undefined`, it's because those properties, at least as you have them listed in your code, do not actually exist on the JSON that's getting sent back to you.

I'd throw a `console.log(items)` in there and take a look at what's actually getting returned to you, and make sure for those other columns you are using the correct property name from the returned JSON.

Comment: thanks you helped a lot